# Using NextJS, is there a way to set up multiple websites that looks very similar with a single repository?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gatsby, next.js13

Currently I am using GatsbyJS with a plugin called Gatsby Theme.

This allows us to achieve having multiple websites with very few difference for each location we have throughout the states.

For example, we have these domains that looks almost identical but with just few texts within those sites. For one of the differences we currently use Firebase to get the data and one of the example is the address.

```
www.exampleNewYork.com
www.exampleFlorida.com
www.exampleCalifornia.com
```

I'm thinking of using NextJS for the next similar project and I'm wondering how I can achieve this using NextJS as I'm not familiar with and not sure where to start looking.

Thanks!